# Cookies sharing for each firefox driver instance

Tags: cookies, session-cookies, selenium-grid, parallel-testing

I have multiple tests that could be run in parallel on a single machine with multiple Firefox drivers. Given that the application will also be writing/reading from cookies, is there any existing solution that deals when it comes to cookies sharing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use profiles , have different profiles and launch the firefox driver with the profiles. look at [this](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver)